# Xcode 12 collapse all build targets

Tags: macos, ide, xcode12

Using Xcode 12, my build contains many targets. After the build ends, the Report Navigator displays the issues for each target in an expanded mode. To collapse, I have to close the target nodes one by one which is a great nuisance. Even after closing all, the moment you navigate around and go back to that page - the target reports are expanded again.

Tried:

- cmd + click (alt + click, cmd + shift + click) on one of the target nodes.
- Right click on one of the nodes, select "Collapse all transcripts".

None help. Any advice?

**EDIT**: clarification: the question is about multiple **targets**, i.e.:

```
Build Target t1
  error 1
  error 2
Build Target t2
  error 3
  error 4
```

And trying to collapse to this:

```
> Build Target t1
> Build Target t2
```

Comment: Have you tried holding option and using the left/right arrow keys?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I understand that you tried it and it works for you?

Comment: Yes. Open a report, select everything (command-A), then press option-left arrow. This also works in Finder, and really any kind of outline view on macOS.

Comment: Didn't work. Are you sure it works for TARGETS? See my clarification edit.

Comment: Yes. Click on a target so it is highlighted. Press command-A to highlight all targets and transcripts. Hold the alt/option key and press the left arrow key.

Comment: [Here's a recording](https://gfycat.com/improbableesteemedfirecrest)

Comment: Yes!! Works like a charm - the left arrow is enough - no need for the option key.
Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply select any line in the report, press ⌘A to select everything, then press the left arrow key to collapse all the targets.

[image]